# id argument in onItemCheckedStateChanged() is the same for several rows in ExpandableListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview, simplecursoradapter, android-cursor

I have `ExpandableListView` with `SimpleCursorTreeAdapter` and use `ActionMode` with it.
In the callback method `onItemCheckedStateChanged   [long id]` argument is repeated for several rows. And when i call `setItemChecked()` for some row, i get wrong item activated.
How this `[long id]` is calculated? Is it based on `[_id]` in `cursor`?

Answer (score 0):

`long id` is independent of `_id` in the `cursor`.. `long id` is just the row id of the `ExpandableListView` .. see [details](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html) [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener.html#onItemCheckedStateChanged%28android.view.ActionMode,%20int,%20long,%20boolean%29)

Comment: do you know how [long id] is calculated? Then why it is the same for several rows if it is independent of _id?